# Enviar datos desde servidor hacia AZURE usando JSON

Tags: php, json, azure

Tengo archivos `php` que lo que hacen es insertar,mostrar,eliminar datos a través de json, pero los tengo montados en otro servidor, funcionaba cuando utilizaba `phpmyadmin` pero me cambie a `azure` y no se como se tiene que realizar para hacer estas operaciones.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos estimado! Primero lo primero, `Azure` y `PhpMyAdmin` son dos cosas completamente distintas.

`PhpMyAdmin` te permite administrar tus bases de datos `MySQL` a través de un cliente web.

Por otro lado `Azure` es una plataforma Cloud en la cual puedes tener bases de datos MYSQL, VM's, Websites y muchos servicios más en dos modelos distintos : IAAS y PAAS. ([Más sobre esto...](http://bugs4fun.com/2015/08/27/que-es-azure/)).

Dicho esto, probablemente tengas que hacer lo siguiente:

1. [Migrar tu base de datos `Mysql` a `azure`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/store-php-create-mysql-database)
2. [Migrar tu codigo php a `Azure` `App Services`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-configure)

Espero te sirva!